# Gradle - Connection to maven repository refused

Tags: android-studio, gradle

In my build.gradle, I have:

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
     repositories {
          mavenCentral()
     }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The error I get is as follows:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not resolve org.greenrobot.eventbus:3.0.0:.
>        Required by:
>            MyApp:app:unspecified
>   Could not resolve org.greenrobot.eventbus:3.0.0:.
>   Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/greenrobot/eventbus/3.0.0//3.0.0-.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/greenrobot/eventbus/3.0.0//3.0.0-.pom'.
>   Connection to https://repo1.maven.org refused
>   Could not resolve org.greenrobot.eventbus:3.0.0:.
>   Could not get resource 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/greenrobot/eventbus/3.0.0//3.0.0-.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/greenrobot/eventbus/3.0.0//3.0.0-.pom'.
>   Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused

I am behind a proxy, so I tried entering my proxy settings inside gradle.properties as system properties. It still will not connect, but the error in that case is this:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not resolve org.greenrobot.eventbus:3.0.0:.
>        Required by:
>            MyApp:app:unspecified
>   Could not resolve org.greenrobot.eventbus:3.0.0:.
>   Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/greenrobot/eventbus/3.0.0//3.0.0-.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/greenrobot/eventbus/3.0.0//3.0.0-.pom'.
>   myproxy.com
>   Could not resolve org.greenrobot.eventbus:3.0.0:.
>   Could not get resource 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/greenrobot/eventbus/3.0.0//3.0.0-.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/greenrobot/eventbus/3.0.0//3.0.0-.pom'.
>   myproxy.com